# Map AWS Network ACL to Network Firewall Rule Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

My current setup have one network ACL for each subnet. I wanted to add aws network firewall into my setup.

1. Network ACL is stateless. For inbound, we specify the source, protocol, port(s). Same for outbound. But for Network Firewall stateless rule group, there is source and destination together. How can I map the current network ACL to Network Firewall stateless rule group?
2. If I have Network ACL, WAF, Shield Advanced, do I still need Network Firewall?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve. You can't remove ACL. Each subnet has one.

Comment: @Marcin I mean not the default network ACL. I meant the custom network ACL.

Comment: I don't get the question 1. Is it a theoretical question or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @Bob for network acl is stateless. For inbound, we specify the source, protocol, port(s). Same for outbound. But for network firewall stateless rule group, there is source and destination together. So I am a little confused on how to map from current network ACL to network firewall stateless rule group.

Comment: NACL will just allow/deny traffic based on protocol and ports. The fine tuning for the allowed services you will do with SG / Firewall. There should always have ingress and egress fields to be configured... I am struggling to understand what you want to achieve...